# Not getting token in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using fire base for push notification in react-native.

For getting token I am using this code

```
const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();

if (fcmToken) {
  this.sendFcmToken(fcmToken);
  // user has a device token
}
```

But I am not getting token even if user have permission for token access.

I am using firebase 5.1.1

`"react-native-firebase": "^5.1.1"`

I don't want to upgrade version, so what I can do?

I think problem is with `getToken()` method as its deprecated so please suggest an alternative for it.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: You don't seem to be checking for errors anywhere.  Add error checking to your code, post the new code, and include any error messages along with that.  We should be able to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: `getToken()`  still working in my project.. what is the error are you getting?